# Merging List<T> and List<Optional<T>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given:

```
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            10, 12
    ));

    List<Optional<Integer>> optionalIntegers = Arrays.asList(
            Optional.of(5),
            Optional.empty(),
            Optional.of(3),
            Optional.of(2),
            Optional.empty()
    );

    List<Integer> unwrappedOptionals = optionalIntegers.stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    integers.addAll(unwrappedOptionals);
```

Is there some better way of unwrapping `Optional`s, or other way of merging them both into a `List<Integer>`? It feels extremely wasteful to collect them into a new `List` before doing `addAll()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With new Java-9 [`Optional.stream()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) method it can be written this way:

```
optionalIntegers.stream()
                .flatMap(Optional::stream)
                .forEach(integers::add);
```

Prior to Java-9 you can add such method into your own utility class:

```
public class StreamUtil {
    public static <T> Stream<T> fromOptional(Optional<T> opt) {
        return opt.isEmpty() ? Stream.empty() : Stream.of(opt.get());
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
optionalIntegers.stream()
                .flatMap(StreamUtil::fromOptional)
                .forEach(integers::add);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to create an intermediate `List`, add the filtered elements directly to the original `integers` `List` using `forEach()` instead of `collect()` :

```
optionalIntegers.stream()
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .forEach(integers::add);
```

Or, as Sergey Lagutin suggested, you can use `Optional`'s `map()` and `orElse()` methods with a `flatMap()` :

```
optionalIntegers.stream()
                .flatMap(o -> o.map(Stream::of)
                               .orElse(Stream.empty()))
                .forEach(integers::add);
```

Comment: not sure that my idea is good but we combine `filter` and `map` to one `flatMap` operation: `flatMap(o -> o.map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty()))`

Comment: @SergeyLagutin That also works. I'm not sure which is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the other form of ifPresent

```
ifPresent(Consumer<T>) void
```

With a simple forEach one could write:

```
optionalIntegers.stream().forEach(optional -> optional.ifPresent(integers::add));
```

Comment: Thanks! While every answer is correct, I felt this was the solution I prefered and marked it accordingly. Replacing `isPresent` and `get` with a `ifPresent` felt like the most correct way, to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to merge them into an independent `List<Integer>` you can use [`Stream::concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) like:

```
List<Integer> merged = Stream.concat(
         integers.stream(), 
         optionalIntegers.stream().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)
     ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you! We probably have many occurences where both `Stream`s are available straight away and using a concat would be cleaner.